# Instantiate Fragment dynamically by class name

Tags: java, android, list, class, fragment

I have a main activity with a menu to navigate through the page. To dynamize my code, I created my adapter with the name and the class of all of my fragments.

```
public class MenuItem {

    private String title;
    private Class className;
    ...
}
```

I have my adapter created that way :

```
    ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems=new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

    menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Home", null, HomeFragment.class, R.drawable.ic_drawer, true));
    menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Schedule", null, ScheduleFragment.class, R.drawable.ic_drawer, false));
```

In my menu onClickListener, I want to directly open the page without doing any conditional statement :

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Class c =  ((MenuItem) mMenuAdapter.getItem(position)).getClassName();
        Fragment fragment = ??? //How do I create a Fragment dynamically ? 

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_container, fragment).commit();
```

This way of coding is used for the Activity, but it's simpler in that case because to change an activity, we're using only startActivity with the name of the activity, not its instance.

Do I need to use reflection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just invoke [Class#newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) method:

```
Fragment fragment = c.newInstance();
```

Make sure you have the default constructor on your Fragment class.

You'll also need to wrap this construnction into try-catch clause, because `newInstance()` throws couple of exceptions - `InstantiationException` and `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Already tried it : it throws a java.lang.InstantiationException

Comment: What does it say in the exception's message? **Edit:** from the documentation - *InstantiationException is thrown if this Class represents an abstract class, an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or void; or if the class has no nullary constructor; or if the instantiation fails for some other reason.* I suppose your fragments don't have no-arguments constructors.

Comment: I was missing the try catch + the cast

Comment: Also, rather than caching the actual class, you could just keep the class name, and use `Fragment.instantiate(String classname)` to create the new instance.

Comment: @kcoppock interesting, didn't know about this one. `instantiate()` doesn't have one-argument version, though, we need to pass `Context` instance also.

Comment: @aga ah yeah, forgot the context param. :)